# Can svelte use composable functions?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I am coming from vue and used to composable functions. I am trying to figure out the way to do this in svelte

So I make a js file and import store and then was trying to make a function that I could call on multiple components and act individually

swipe.js file

```
import { writable, derived, get } from 'svelte/store';

function createSwipe() {

  const dyFromStart = writable(0)

  function moveEvent(eventType, val){
    console.log('moveEvent', eventType, val, get(dyFromStart))
    dyFromStart.update(n => n + 1);
  }

  const dxScore = derived(dyFromStart, $dyFromStart => $dyFromStart + 3)
  const dyScore = derived(dyFromStart, $dyFromStart => Math.round($dyFromStart + 100));
  return {
    moveEvent,
    dxScore,
    dyScore, 
  };
}

export const swipe = createSwipe();
```

then in .svelte component import function in script and decompose into subparts

```svelte
<script>
import { swipe } from "$lib/swipe";
let { moveEvent, dxScore, dyScore } = swipe
</script>
<p>{$dxScore}{$dyScore}</p>
<button on:click="() => moveEvent">button</button>
```

Well eventually I want to turn into a swipe component hence name but trying to get fundamentals down. So I want to be able to have unique store for each component and for this if I use multiple of this .svelte component the state is shared amongst all.

And not just like three idk modal.svelte components I want to use swipe for a bunch of diff components maybe a photoViewer.svelte right just generic swipe function and use same code for all.

or would I just have to keep the state like `const dyFromStart = writable(0)` be just `let dyFromStart = 0` in each .svelte component and pass it into a pure js function that returns results and update local .svelte variables

Adding this as the non store more pure js things I was trying but couldn't get to be reactive so accepting the answer below on store method that worked and sounds like is the correct approach

```
export function createSwipe() {
 let dyFromStart = 0

  function moveEvent(eventType, val){
    console.log('moveEvent', eventType, val, dyFromStart, dxScore(), dyScore())
    dyFromStart++
  }

  function dxScore(){ return dyFromStart + 3 }
  // const dzScore = derived(dyFromStart, $dyFromStart => $dyFromStart + 3)
  const dyScore = () => Math.round(dyFromStart + 100)
  
  return {
    moveEvent,
    dxScore,
    dyScore,
    dyFromStart
  };
```

```
export function createSwipe() {
let dyFromStart = 0
  let dxScore = dyFromStart + 3
  let dyScore = Math.round(dyFromStart + 100)

  function moveEvent(eventType, val){
    console.log('moveEvent', eventType, val, dyFromStart, dxScore, dyScore)
    dyFromStart++
    dxScore = dyFromStart + 3
    dyScore = Math.round(dyFromStart + 100)
  }

  return {
    moveEvent,
    dxScore,
    dyScore,
    dyFromStart
  };
```

I suppose that works fine just not reactive with $ and need to call to update a diff local var if doing that

this would seem most sveltey to me or something like it as far as composable function type style not store type

```
export function createSwipe() {
 let dyFromStart = 0

  function moveEvent(eventType, val){
    console.log('moveEvent', eventType, val)
    dyFromStart++
  }

  $: dxScore = dyFromStart + 3
  $: dyScore = Math.round($dyFromStart + 100)
  return {
    moveEvent,
    dxScore,
    dyScore, 
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the question fully, so I try to reiterate first what I think you want:

- You want to use your swipe function in multiple places
- Each usage of that swipe function should be independent of all others

If that's correct, then the answer is simple: Don't do `export const swipe = createSwipe()`. Delete that part and instead export the create function to use directly within your components. That way you create a new independent instance each time:

```svelte
<script>
  import { createSwipe } from "$lib/swipe";
  let { moveEvent, dxScore, dyScore } = createSwipe()
</script>
<p>{$dxScore}{$dyScore}</p>
<button on:click="() => moveEvent">button</button>
```

Comment: Excellent yes this is exactly what I wanted thanks! Follow up question is does the code need to (or is it recommended) to be using store type vars or would it work with plain js. When I tried with plain js I didnt quite figure out how to have the vars be reactive and tried having like $: locDxScore = dxScore or as var dxScore() and wouldn't be reactive. If called button and console log it would call it and show correct val but  I'd rather it just be automatic if possible. I'm not 100% sure on all the pros and cons of the store stuff since new to svelte so yeah is it better or worse here

Comment: Usage of the store is the correct choice in this case in order to get the reactivity, automatic updates etc that you want.

Comment: I added some of the non store things I was trying that weren't reactive (or I wasn't doing fully right) but ok great sounds like store is way to go anyway thanks. Is this generally true also as best approach? Like a let variable in .svelte <script> is reactive but can't move that exact code (no store) external and bring in and work same way reactive and all

Comment: Because if I have really long js code I mean not ideal to have super long js code in one file but also not ideal to have to convert everything to store to move to external file right? Seems like should work same way from external file I just have to do it right but maybe I'm wrong